# Php - on click counter and forward to another web page

Tags: php, counter, forward

I have the following script which I'm trying to achieve this:  When a user clicks a link, it activates the counter, and then forwards the visitor to another website.  It's forwarding to the other site just fine, but it's not increasing the counter. If I take the forward out, it works fine, so my question is how can I accomplish a click, count it, and forward to another website?

```
    <?php 

/** 
 * Create an empty text file called couponsbyemailB.txt and  
 * upload to the same directory as the page you want to  
 * count hits for. 
 *  
 * Add this line of code on your page: 
 * <?php include "freecouponsbyemailB.php"; ?> 
 */ 

// Open the file for reading -- tracks by banner clicked
$fp = fopen("couponsbyemailB.txt", "r"); 

// Get the existing count 
$count = fread($fp, 1024); 

// Close the file 
fclose($fp); 

// Add 1 to the existing count 
$count = $count + 1; 

// Display the number of hits 
// If you don't want to display it, comment out this line 
//echo "<p>Page views:" . $count . "</p>"; 

// Reopen the file and erase the contents -- tracks by banner clicked
$fp = fopen("couponsbyemailB.txt", "w"); 

// Write the new count to the file 
fwrite($fp, $count); 

// Close the file 
fclose($fp); 

header('Location: http://www.inboxdollars.com/?r=ref18222798'); // redirect to new web page

?>
```

Comment: Where does the click take you?  How do you call the count updater?

Comment: Hi Jay, I call the freecouponsbyemailB.php file (the script shown in my original post) like this <a href = "http://www.example.com/freecouponsbyemailB.php"><img src = "myimage.jpg"></a>

Answer (score 1):

Updating the counter can be done much easier:

```
$count = file_get_contents("couponsbyemailB.txt");
$count = $count + 1;
file_put_contents("couponsbyemailB.txt", $count);
```

Keep in mind that refreshing the page will not trigger the counter again, you have to call your php file again.

Comment: Thank you ByteHamster - that is much more simple.  I've swapped my previous code out for that, and I'm still having the issue with it not adding each click unless I remove the header line.  With the header line, I still have issues.

Comment: I have just tested the code - working fine for me (even with the header). Keep in mind that refreshing the page will not trigger the counter again, you have to call your php file again.

Comment: I hadn't though of that ByteHamster; You're right! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Okay nice. Please accept my answer if it helped you :)